# jQuery + Bootstrap Navigation Bar - How to highlight the link when visited

Tags: jquery, html, css

Please visit this [link](http://codepen.io/dancan07/pen/aJaRMg?editors=1010).

Try to click "Portfolio" link, it should be highlighted with blue background.

But after clicking outside the navigation bar it will be highlighted with blue.

```
    //scrolling
$('nav a').on('click', function() {

    var scrollAnchor = $(this).attr('data-scroll'),
        scrollPoint = $('section[data-anchor="' + scrollAnchor + '"]').offset().top;

    $('body,html').animate({
        scrollTop: scrollPoint
    }, 500);

    return false;

});

//change color
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var windscroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (windscroll) {
        $('section').each(function(i) {
            if ($(this).position().top <= windscroll) {
                $('nav a.active').removeClass('active');
                $('nav a').eq(i).addClass('active');
            }
        });

    }
}).scroll();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
nav a.active,
nav a.active:hover {
  background-color: blue !important;
}
```

Comment: Awesome! You're the answer! :) Double thumbs up!

Comment: Try ignoring !important, Bootstrap is overriding your own styles with .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:focus, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:hover

Comment: Personally I'm not a big fan of 'important', but the CSS already had many styles conflicting each other to prevent the desired output. So to avoid the pain of editing the entire CSS, I had to use 'important'.

Answer (score 1):

Just like hover there is also visited,where you can assign color for the visted links.

```
a:visited {
    color: blue;
}
```